# logical worker replication says the publication does not exist, however this seems to actually exist?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to setup logical replication between two database instances.

I've created a publication on the main db, and a subscription on the replica. Specifically:

on main db:

```
create publication chris for all tables;
```

on replica db:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION chris
    CONNECTION 'host=localhost port=5540 dbname=finder connect_timeout=10'
    PUBLICATION chris;
```

However for some reason the replica does not seem to be recognizing the publication (essentially `ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  publication "chris" does not exist`) (logs from the replica):

```
Oct 20 18:18:31 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:31.013 GMT [289] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 3035) exited with exit code 1
Oct 20 18:18:36 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:36.020 GMT [3036] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "chris" has started
Oct 20 18:18:36 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:36.022 GMT [3036] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  publication "chris" does not exist
Oct 20 18:18:36 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]:         CONTEXT:  slot "chris", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN 0/6BA6EC8
Oct 20 18:18:36 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:36.023 GMT [289] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 3036) exited with exit code 1
Oct 20 18:18:41 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:41.030 GMT [3039] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "chris" has started
Oct 20 18:18:41 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:41.033 GMT [3039] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  publication "chris" does not exist
Oct 20 18:18:41 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]:         CONTEXT:  slot "chris", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN 0/6BA6EC8
Oct 20 18:18:41 test2 8y7qb8wz8ps875yrvpmg9c1zsffls4hy-unit-script-postgresql-start[289]: 2020-10-20 18:18:41.034 GMT [289] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 3039) exited with exit code 1
```

The main db's logs strangely seems to also be showing the same error (`ERROR:  publication "chris" does not exist`):

```
Oct 20 18:22:56 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:22:56.545 GMT [514] CONTEXT:  slot "chris", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN >
Oct 20 18:23:01 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:01.555 GMT [515] LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "chris"
Oct 20 18:23:01 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:01.555 GMT [515] DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after 0/6BA6E60, reading WAL from 0/6BA6E28.
Oct 20 18:23:01 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:01.555 GMT [515] LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/6BA6E28
Oct 20 18:23:01 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:01.555 GMT [515] DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
Oct 20 18:23:01 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:01.556 GMT [515] ERROR:  publication "chris" does not exist
Oct 20 18:23:01 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:01.556 GMT [515] CONTEXT:  slot "chris", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN >
Oct 20 18:23:06 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:06.566 GMT [518] LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "chris"
Oct 20 18:23:06 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:06.566 GMT [518] DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after 0/6BA6E60, reading WAL from 0/6BA6E28.
Oct 20 18:23:06 pgtestpublic 22rj0nr8pn1k0r3q8q6pxixp6hn2zi4i-unit-script-postgresql-start[260]: 2020-10-20 18:23:06.566 GMT [518] LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/6BA6E28
```

However I do see the correct expected output from:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_publication;
select * from pg_catalog.pg_publication;
```

on the main database.

What could I investigate further? And what may likely be the cause of the error?

Comment: It is probably some simple user error, like not connecting to the correct database name.

Comment: Why would the main db be showing a similar error though in that case? As it's not connecting to anything externally.

Comment: The main database **instance** is showing the error.  I don't know what database that error shows up in, as you don't seem to be logging the database name in your `log_line_prefix` (unless you are, I don't know what test2 and pgtestpublic represent, but I don't think they are the dbname.)

Comment: I was able to fix this kind of issue by first creating the publication and then creating the replication slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot to specify a username and password. Perhaps it used some default user/password combination by default. Otherwise, maybe a misleading error message.

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION chris
    CONNECTION 'host=localhost username=example password=example port=5540 dbname=finder connect_timeout=10'
    PUBLICATION chris;
```